# How do I insert a row into the middle of a table?

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

I got two pieces of A4 paper in ms word
[image: Two parted A4 paper]
i want insert 2 name in each part  using Mail Merge wizard

I create the following table in an Access database:

[image]

but when i try to insert name in Parts,word insert same name(ex:Jeson Park) in two part
but i want to insert one name in one part and one other in another part(ex:Jeson park in part one and Amin Mohammadi in part two)
its seem it cannot done Unless i insert new field in access database
inserting new field need to change table rows
I want to insert a new row between rows number 3 and 4.

Is there a way to insert a row into the middle of a table OR Insert two Different row in same word page?

Comment: Access tables simply hold records. They are not like Excel where you can add rows. Reports, forms and queries are used to view data in the order you define. If you want to view the table in a specific order, sort the view. Give us more details of what you are trying to do so we can help you.

Comment: tnx For replay .i give more detail about my wonderful table!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike Excel, Access is a database and not a spreadsheet software. The data displayed in the screen you included is not a table *per se*: rows and columns are one of the many ways of displaying data. You can sort the data any way you want, but it will only change the way they are displayed *currently*, not the way they are stored. (In this example, they seem to be sorted by ID.)

> You can't really put it into the first or any other real position. All
>   views on an Access database are sorted by some field or other, often,
>   the order entered. You can give a new record a field value that
>   happens to put it at a particular place in the view, but the actual
>   record is at an uncontrollable place on the physical database.
>
> In fact, if you try to insert a record between two records in a
>   Datasheet view (the one that resembles a spreadsheet) by
>   right-clicking in the left border and selecting Insert a Record,
>   you'll pop to the last visible record and start entering there. Adding
>   data would then probably re-sort the new record to its ordered place
>   according to the view.

([source](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101011115531AAYU1f0))

> You must stop immediately and forever in thinking "rows" when working
>   with Access. They are not rows.
>
> If you have records with prime keys 123 and 124 and they are integers,
>   you cannot put anything between them. PERIOD. To allow yourself the
>   luxury of putting things helter-skelter on a display, you need to
>   either be preprared to renumber things frequently or put a secondary
>   key on the table so that your key is comprised of two parts. Then use
>   the second part to force order to be a certain way.

([source](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=128421))

To add new data between "3" and "4" you'd have to modify EVERY data after "3" and increment its ID, and then insert a new data with ID being "3".

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'Sequence number' field to the table.
For each record you add, number it 10, 20, 30 and so on.
This way, if you need to add a record and have it display between 10 and 20, add a new record and Sequence number it 15 and sort the table display by Sequence number>Sort smallest to largest.
The sorted order will display 10, 15, 20, 30.
Feel free to make the increments between Sequence numbers as large as you like.
If you think you might need to add more than 9 records between 10 and 20, then Sequence number the records by 100: 100, 200, 300...